# convert string to uint8_t array

Tags: c++

I have string (key_str) of size 32 bytes. I want to store each bytes in uint8_t array element key[32].
I tried the following:

```
string key_str = "00001000200030004000500060007000";
uint32_t key[32] ;
uint8_t* k = reinterpret_cast <uint8_t*>(&key_str[0]);

for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
   {
    key[j]= *k;
    k++;
    cout<<bitset<8>(key[j])<<endl;
   }
```

but the MSB 4 bits of the output is always 0011 because of representation of characters (0,1,...) so how can I convert it to integer?

Output sample:
00110000
..
00110001
..
00110010
..

Comment: Do you have a guarantee that the string always will have at least 32 bytes of input (in given example, sure you have, but in your real code?)? If not, absolutely add a length check or iterate only up to `std::min(key_str.length(), 32)`. Instead of literal 32, prefer using `sizeof(key)/sizeof(*key)`, you can then change array size without danger of forgetting to adjust the other places. If you use `std::array` instead of raw array, you can use its `size()` member instead of the ugly, but otherwise necessary division by size of first element (be aware of `sizeof` always giving size in *bytes*!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could use some other work, but the bug, if I understand you correctly, is because **you don't compensate for the offset of the ASCII character value of `'0'`**.

Try this (as close as I found it reasonable to stick to your code):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string key_str = "00001000200030004000500060007000";
    uint8_t key[32] ;

    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {
        key[j] =  static_cast<uint8_t>(key_str[j] - '0');
        cout << bitset<8>(key[j]) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000001
00000000
00000000
00000010
...
```

So the key thing here in regards to your question is the subtraction of `'0'` right here: `key[j] =  static_cast<uint8_t>(key_str[j] - '0');`.

Also, if you say

> I want to store each bytes in `uint8_t` array element `key[32]`

then perhaps it's by mistake that you defined it to be `uint32_t key[32];` instead of `uint8_t key[];`. I've allowed myself to correct it.